# Check if a string contains at least one of the strings stored in an array of substrings

Tags: .net, string, vb.net

How can I refactor this into a oneliner or at least some native functions, without dramatically affecting performance? I will be checking about 100 strings against 20 substrings. That should not last for more than 200-300ms, on regular 5 year old pro laptops.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicates whether the string includes at least one of the provided substrings.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="MyString">The string this extension applies to.</param>
    ''' <param name="SubStrings">The array of substrings that may be contained within the main string. Best performance when low index values contain the substrings the most likely to match.</param>
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Function ContainsAtLeastOneOf(MyString As String, SubStrings As String()) As Boolean

        For Each SubString As String In SubStrings
            If MyString.Contains(SubString) Then Return True
        Next

        Return False

    End Function
```

I found many solutions where people check that a set of strings all contain the same substring, but was not able to find topics addressing the reverse.
I have several solutions in mind, but none of them seem clean enough. I am guessing there must be a more obvious way of achieving this.

At the moment, the options I can think of are:

1. Regular expression: `Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(MyString, string.format("{0}|{1}|{2}", SubStr1, SubStr2, SubStr3, ...))`
2. Ugly OrElse: `If MyString.Contains(SubStr1) OrElse MyString.Contains(SubStr2) OrElse ...`
3. I have the intuition there is something with `IEnumerable.Intersect(...)`, but that would loop over a `Char` instead of the `String`.

c# answers are acceptable.

Comment: If this works and meets your performance requirements, why change it?

Comment: To reduce maintenance and complexity in case there would be a native function for this kind of check, which I expect there would be?

Comment: Basically: Did I just re-invent the wheel?

Comment: **_100 strings against 20 substrings._** takes <.001 ms when made into single regex ternary with refactoring. http://regexformat.com

Comment: Post a link to the regex, I'll help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Const so = "StackOverFlow"
        Dim t1 = Now
        For i = 0 To 100
            Console.WriteLine(so.ContainsAtLeastOneOf(New String() {"over1", "over"}, True))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine((Now - t1).TotalMilliseconds)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Function ContainsAtLeastOneOf(myString As String, subStrings As String(), Optional caseInsensitive As Boolean = False) _
        As Boolean

        If caseInsensitive Then
            Return subStrings.Any(Function(subString) myString.ToLower().Contains(subString.ToLower()))
        End If
        Return subStrings.Any(Function(subString) myString.Contains(subString))
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Perfect, `subStrings.Any(Function(s) myString.Contains(s))` is what I was looking for. Much better than having to include an extension and maintain it. I guess `.Any` will stop looping as soon as one item returns `True`?

Comment: Yes it does. As soon as it finds a match, the criteria is satified.

Comment: Instead of `myString.ToLower().Contains(subString.ToLower())`, it is safer to use `myString.IndexOf(subString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0`. (Other StringComparison options are available.)

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic - is it me or should the Returns be switched? matchCase seems to imply that the case is must match.

Comment: @AndrewMorton why is that? Could you develop what risk there is? I always use .ToLower() as I find it very readable, but if you tell me there are drawbacks..

Comment: @Ama In some languages, ToLower() doesn't give the same character as the lowercase version of some letters: [The Turkish İ Problem and Why You Should Care](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/). (The comments in that article are also very informative, although the link to Jon Skeet's talk on the subject (and related matters) should now [link to this on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3nPJ-yK-LU).)